# How to convert a string into a color

Tags: c#, string, colors

I am trying to convert a string like the following: `{100,100,100}` into a `System.Drawing.Color` object. What is the best approach for accomplishing this task?

Comment: what have you [***tried yourself***](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched? please **edit** your question to include more information. 
please also read [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: "into a color", what exact data type is that? `System.Drawing.Color`? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
private Color GetColorByString(string String)
    {
        string[] ColorValues = String.Split(',', '.', ' ');

        for (int i = 0; i < ColorValues.Length; i++)
        {
            ColorValues[i] = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"[^\d]").Replace(ColorValues[i], "");
        }
        try
        {
            return Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt32(ColorValues[0]), Convert.ToInt32(ColorValues[1]), Convert.ToInt32(ColorValues[2]));
        }
        catch { return new Color(); }
    }
```

And you can use it like this:

```
Color NewColor = GetColorByString("{100,100,100}");
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks.